# Is the trivial representation a subrepresentation of a tensor power of any irreducible complex representation of a finite group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group,  $V$ an irreducible complex representation and $\mathbb{1}$ the trivial representation.

*Question*: $\exists n >0$ such that $\mathbb{1} \le V^{\otimes n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Yes*

1. If $n := \dim V$, then $V^{\otimes n}$ contains the $1$-dimensional representation $\bigwedge^n V$ as a summand, so we may assume $\dim V = 1$.
2. If $V$ is $1$-dimensional, it corresponds to a character $\chi: G\to {\mathbb C}^{\times}$, and since $G$ is finite, the $|G|$-th tensor power of $V$ will be trivial.

Comment: Nice, this seems more generally applicable than my answer.

Comment: I had the exact same idea. You were quicker. Congrats and +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, let $N\leq G$ be the kernel of the representation, so $V$ is a faithful $G/N$-module.

Now we know that there is an $n$ such that the trivial module is a $G/N$-submodule of $V^{\otimes n}$ (some number at most one less than the number of distinct values the character of $V$ takes will work). But now this $G/N$-submodule is also a $G$-submodule, and it is clearly still the trivial module.

Comment: Curious. I don't recall seeing the result relating $n$ to the number of values of the character. Is that well known and/or easy to show? Actually, if $G/N\cong C_2$ and the character takes two values, then the first power won't suffice. Is that a problem?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It is Theorem 4.3 in Isaacs' book on character theory, and it seems to be due to Burnside-Brauer. The proof is not terribly tricky, but now that I looked it up I realize that I slightly misstated it, so editing.